# Firefox - как открывать новые окна во вкладках?

Tags: firefox

Вопрос - как настроить firefox, чтобы он открывал новые окна во вкладках.

Есть сайты, которые не которые свои ссылки открывают в новом окне, а нужно чтоб они  принудительно открывались во вкладке.

Такое возможно?

И если возможно, то как?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то открывай ссылки mouse3 (клик по колёсику)

Comment: не всегда есть под рукой мышь... и это я не для себя... просто в настройках ФФ стоит галочка открывать новые окна как вкладки, а не которые ссылки, все равно  в новом окне

Comment: ctrl + click попробуй

Comment: это хорошо, а вот не все люди  эти сделают, а надо бы максимально без "лишних телодвижений" ...  потому что  - я нажму, а вот не я - не нажмет

Comment: пусть тарелкой зажмут ctrl :D
а если серьезно поищи расширение для ff

Comment: ищу расширения... пока нет успехов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если mouse3 или ctrl + click не вариант, то
[данное расширения для Firefox решит твою задачу](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/open-link-in-new-tab/?src=userprofile)
по умолчанию все отключено, чтобы включить зайди в настройки, там 2 уровня настроек.

p.s. у себя протестил, все работает.

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо.